# How to display RDF data described by Fresnel vocabulary?

Tags: javascript, rdf, semantic-web, fresnel

I am studying Semantic web while trying to create a simple single page application (SPA).

The SPA should be able to display various rdf data (and also allow the user to create new ontologies in a user friendly way).

I have full controll of the format of the ontologies (meaning I can state if they are represented as RDF/XML, ntripples, turtle etc. and also I can decide, if I want to use ontologies to describe how the data should be displayed).

From what I read in the [Fresnel Manual](http://www.w3.org/2005/04/fresnel-info/manual/) I think this can be a good way to describe the "look" of the ontologies.

I discovered what looks like a [JQuery fresnel engine](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/55722372/), but am missing some examples on how to use this.

Questions:

1. How can I use such an engine to display the data below?
2. Is Fresnel something that is recommended to use for this issue?
3. If not, what do you recommend?

**An example from the Fresnel manual:**

**RDF object to be displayed**

```
:Chris rdf:type foaf:Person ;
       foaf:name "Chris Bizer" ;
       foaf:mbox <mailto:chris@bizer.de> ;
       foaf:mbox <mailto:bizer@gmx.de> ;
       foaf:depiction <http://www.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/suhl/ueber_uns/team/Fotos/ChrisPassbild.jpg> .
```

**Fresnel styling information:**

```
:foafGroup rdf:type fresnel:Group ;
           fresnel:stylesheetLink <http://www.example.org/example.css> ;
           fresnel:containerStyle "background-color: white;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ; 

:foafPersonFormat rdf:type fresnel:Format ;
                  fresnel:classFormatDomain foaf:Person ;
                  fresnel:resourceStyle "background-color: gray;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
                  fresnel:group :foafGroup .

:nameFormat rdf:type fresnel:Format ;
            fresnel:propertyFormatDomain foaf:name ;
            fresnel:propertyStyle "border-top: solid black;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
            fresnel:labelStyle "font-weight: bold;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
            fresnel:group :foafGroup .

:urlFormat rdf:type fresnel:Format ;
           fresnel:propertyFormatDomain foaf:homepage ;
           fresnel:propertyFormatDomain foaf:mbox ;
           fresnel:value fresnel:externalLink ;
           fresnel:propertyStyle "border-top: solid black;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
           fresnel:labelStyle "font-weight: bold;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
           fresnel:group :foafGroup .

:depictFormat rdf:type fresnel:Format ;
              fresnel:propertyFormatDomain foaf:depiction ;
              fresnel:label fresnel:none ;
              fresnel:value fresnel:image ;
              fresnel:propertyStyle "border-top: solid black;"^^fresnel:stylingInstructions ;
              fresnel:group :foafGroup .
```

Comment: I know I am tip toeing on the edge of a too general question, but I still feel this can be valuable for other users in the future..

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use such an engine to display the data below?

Use [FSL](http://www.w3.org/2005/04/fresnel-info/fsl/) to map nodes to DOM selectors

> Is Fresnel something that is recommended to use for this issue?

It seems the [Linked Data Platform](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LDP_Implementations) has subsumed this effort.

**References**

- [RDF Visualization](https://confluence.ontotext.com/display/ResearchSpace/RDF+Visualization)
- [RDFScape](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2367633/)
- [ldpjs: Linked Data Platform Reference Implementation](http://ldpjs.mybluemix.net)

Comment: Good answer, I sill keep waiting until somebody with hands on experience with a fresnel engine replies, but gave u a +1. Thank you for your time.